# Cannot invoke initializer for type UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm following this tutorial on gesture driven apps, http://www.raywenderlich.com/77974/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1

however when I come to implement the recognizer I receive the error

`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIPanGestureRecognizer' with an argument list of type '(target: NSObject -> () -> TableViewCell, action: String)'`

Swift version:
Apple Swift version 2.0 (swiftlang-700.0.59 clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var originalCenter = CGPoint()
    var deleteOnDragRelease = false

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // gradient layer for cell
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        let color1 = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.2).CGColor as CGColorRef
        let color2 = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.1).CGColor as CGColorRef
        let color3 = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor as CGColorRef
        let color4 = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.1).CGColor as CGColorRef
        gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2, color3, color4]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.01, 0.95, 1.0]
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }

    // add a pan recognizer
    var recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
    recognizer.delegate = self
    addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    //MARK: - horizontal pan gesture methods
    func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // 1
        if recognizer.state == .Began {
            // when the gesture begins, record the current center location
            originalCenter = center
        }
        // 2
        if recognizer.state == .Changed {
            let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)
            center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y)
            // has the user dragged the item far enough to initiate a delete/complete?
            deleteOnDragRelease = frame.origin.x < -frame.size.width / 2.0
        }
        // 3
        if recognizer.state == .Ended {
            // the frame this cell had before user dragged it
            let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y,
                width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
            if !deleteOnDragRelease {
                // if the item is not being deleted, snap back to the original location
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self.frame = originalFrame})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your code on how you are using it as I just tried with the code in this link and it worked all fine.

Comment: Have you set the target as `self`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've pasted the code. @kabiroberai yes the target is set as self.

Answer (score 1):

`// add a pan recogniser`

From this point on in your code you are writing inside the body of the class rather than in a specific method.

The tutorial states

> Open TableViewCell.swift and add the following code **at the end of the overridden init method**:

So you should probably do that. You've entered the code in the wrong place.

Comment: I can't believe it. Thank you very much jrturton.